# IONIC Push Notification - How to detect why notifications are not delivered on IOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've added Push Notification to my IONIC App using this tutorial: [Using Push Notifications with Firebase in an Ionic + Angular App](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/guides/push-notifications-firebase).

For Android all works fine, but on IOS notifications are not delivered. In my Firebase console there is an information that notification was sent, but nothing appeared on my IPhone. The app is installed by TestFlight (Internal Tests).

Questions would be:

1. How can debug or somehow detect where might be the problem?
2. If there is no way to check it, maybe there is a list of common problems with that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if iOS push notifications permissions are enabled
2. Check to see if you receive a push notifications token when you run your app (it doesn't work on simulator, must be real device)
3. Register push notifications key on your apple developer account and add the key to your firebase app.

Push notifications on iOS is a bit tricky. This tutorial helped me: https://devdactic.com/push-notifications-ionic-capacitor/

Answer (score 0):

Check on the client that it sends a push token to the server.

Check on the server if any errors are reported when pushes are sent to apple.

Check in the console logs whether and pushes appear on your client device.

Check in the app if any push notifications are received.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to following the advice already listed and assuming that you have followed the linked tutorial in detail, what helped me to understand the problems related to my experience with push notifications is to check the validity of the token received from the

```
// On success, we should be able to receive notifications
    PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
      (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
        alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      }
    );
```

is to contact this link [https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/{{Token}}?details=true](https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/%7B%7BToken%7D%7D?details=true)  by entering your received token. If the response contains an error your configuration is incorrect and the error should be found in the changes applied to AppDelegate.swift. Furthermore, I noticed that not always the listener to capture the token does not always activate after a registration and I had to insert in my app also the @capacitor-community/fcmplugin that offers the method

```
FCM.getToken ()
  .then ((r) => alert (`Token $ {r.token}`))
  .catch ((err) => console.log (err));
```

which always returns the token according to my tests, this solution has been applied only for iOS, moreover this plugin also allows you to manage topics efficiently. It's definitely not a clean solution but for me it solved a problem I've been struggling with for days. The last advice I can give you is to pay attention to the activation and deactivation of the listners and to try to use setTimeout () to understand if your failure to work derives from an incorrect initialization of the resources and if these must be moved to the app states where the resources required by the various methods are available.